# How to keep only one radio button selected with React

Tags: radio-button, reactjs

Im trying to learn React by doing a small application with it. My application has two radio buttons and I would like to keep always only one of them checked, but cannot seem to figure out how to uncheck the other button when I select the other one. Instead they both remain selected. Here is a jsfiddle for it:

https://jsfiddle.net/4us5us2o/

And here is the code:

```
var MyRadioButton = React.createClass({
  handleChange: function () {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.myValue)
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <input type="radio" onChange={this.handleChange}>{this.props.myValue}</input>
    )
  }
});


var MyApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      selectedValue: ''
    }
  },
  changeValue: function (newValue) {
    this.setState({selectedValue: newValue })
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyRadioButton onChange={this.changeValue} myValue="A" />
        <MyRadioButton onChange={this.changeValue} myValue="B" /><br></br>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to provide a name attribute on your input elements to mark them as part of the same radio button group.  This standard behavior for an [<input>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element with type radio.

In your example, you could use:

```
<input type="radio" name="myGroupName" onChange={this.handleChange}>{this.props.myValue}</input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add property `checked` and do comparation there.

Example: `checked={this.state.myValue === true}`

I will give you working example, two radio buttons controls value between `true/false`.

https://jsfiddle.net/4hs7v5qb/1/

Comment: This is the easiest way to implement the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just tweaking Chad's answer just in case someone runs into this.

```
<input type="radio" name="myGroupName" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
<span>{this.props.myValue}</span>
```

Don't add any children to the input element as React will throw an error. Just use a span or label next to it for the visible text.